# Strong Scaling of Memory Bound Algorithm

Tags: memory, parallel-processing, mpi

I got the following strong scaling curve for a memory bound algorithm:

[image: Strong Scaling of Memory Bound Algorithm]

Some remarks:

- The benchmark was run on a node with four Quad-Core AMD Opteron™ 8356 processors.
- The dashed line shows the theoretically possible speedup, the solid line the experimentally observed speedup.
- The processes are evenly distributed over the sockets, i.e. the first process goes on socket 1, core 1, the second process on socket 2, core 1, ..., the fifth process on socket 1, core 2, ...
- The FLOP count of the algorithm is 0, so besides some integer arithmetic there is absolutely nothing to compute.

Obviously, after four processes the scaling falls behind the theoretically optimal one. My explanation four this is that each socket has only one memory channel. Therefore, the level of parallelism in the hardware is only min(p, 4), not the number of processors p. We still observe speedups > 4 because a single process cannot fully exploit the bandwidth of the socket as it also spends some time computing memory addresses and stuff.

Do you think this is a reasonable explanation? I would also highly welcome if you corrected minor details, as I am about to write a report and don't want to make a fool out of myself. In particular, I am unsure about the explanation for speedups > 4. After all, computations of new memory addresses can happen at the same as old memory addresses are fetched, so why shouldn't a single process be able to use the full memory bandwidth?

Comment: It's hard to tell exactly without additional details. Is your code embarrassingly parallel or does it use point-to-point and/or collective communication? Does it overlap computation and communication ? How much memory is installed on your node? How much memory is required to solve given your fixed problem size ? What is your fixed problem size ? What is the memory bandwidth per controller ? Is SMT (simultaneous multi threading) enabled on your processors ? If yes, how many threads per core ? Your explanation may be part of the answer, but you need to answer quantitatively, not qualitatively.

Comment: Code is embarassingly parallel. No communication at all is happening. I have 64 GB of memory, of which I use roughly 5 GB. Regarding memory bandwidth, I don't actually know where to look for that number. Is it a property of the chip, the motherboard, the memory unit or possibly all three? (The AMD product description reports a "Integrated Memory Controller Speed" of 2 GHz, but how does that translate into BW?)

Comment: Since I have four quad-cores, I assume I have 4x4=16 independent processing units. Would SMT be found at the level of these 16 units (i.e. the hardware parallelism would even be > 16), or do you mean by SMT whether each single quad-core can truly accommodate 4 independent threads of execution?

Comment: A tool like `lstopo` (`hwloc-ls`) from the `hwloc` library (comes with Open MPI) could shed some light on Massimo's questions. If no `lstopo` is available, parsing (by hand) the output of `cat /proc/cpuinfo` also does the trick.

Comment: Unfortunately, `hwloc` is not available. Also, in its documentation, I have not seen a statement that it could report memory bandwidth. The same holds for `/proc/cpuinfo`: I do find much interesting information there like CPU frequency or cache size, but not memory bandwidth.

Answer (score 1):

Well, my guess is that the problem you are experiencing is due to a combination of factors. Besides cache effects, your main problem here is strictly related to the architecture of your node. What I mean is that your node should have at least two memory banks, if not four. Now, memory is shared among all of the available cores, but memory accesses have different costs depending on how you have mapped processes to cores.

Suppose that your data fits completely in one of the memory banks. Then, the processes mapped to cores for which the memory bank is "local", i.e., accessible through the same memory controller associated to the processor, have direct access to the memory and the access cost is low. However, other processes mapped onto cores belonging to a different processor will incur a much higher cost when accessing the memory since, strictly specking, this access is not local but "remote". This may be part of the problem.

Comment: I assume what you are referring to is the NUMA problem that if a single master thread allocates the memory, the memory will be allocated locally to that thread and therefore it will be remote to many of the slave threads. But can this problem still occur given that in my case each MPI process manages its memory completely independently from all the other processes?

Comment: MPI is one thing, your machine architecture is another one. When one of your processes allocates memory it may well be the case that the actual memory used resides on a different memory bank (suppose that when memory is allocated, the local memory bank is already full), so accessing this memory is much more expensive.